# why string has to be converted to c_str (c string) when passing to printf?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ 
and I know I shouldn't be using printf in c++ while I have cout but this was for experiment sake.
My Question here is Why we have to convert a string to c_str (c string) while passing to printf in c++ while it works fine without converting in cout. 
Below is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;


class A{
int i;
string str;
public:
    A (int value, const string & s) : i(value), str(s){};// constructor
    // setters
    void setvalue(int value) {i = value;}
    void setstr(const string & s) {str = s;}
    //geters
    int get_value() {return i;}
    string get_str() {return str;}

    const char *get_str_cstr() {return str.c_str();}// I didn't get why we have to declare constant


};

int main(){
// new code
A obj1 = {11, "Jill"};

cout<<"value is : "<<obj1.get_value()<<" string is "<<obj1.get_str()<<endl;

// Now we wil change the values in A
obj1.setvalue(2);
obj1.setstr("Jack");
cout<<"value after change is : "<<obj1.get_value()<<" string after change is "<<obj1.get_str()<<endl;

// now we will use printf where get_str dosen't not work


//Error: for below commented printf function
/*In function 'int main()':|
error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
*/

//printf("Value is %d and String is %s",obj1.get_value(),obj1.get_str());

// hence we declare a new char * get_str_cstr to make it work in printf;

printf("Value is %d and String is %s",obj1.get_value(),obj1.get_str_cstr());

return 0;}
```

I have also provided the error in program comments.
Thank you!

Comment: `printf` is specified to be able to handle char pointers. It is not specified to handle elephants, mortgage crises or `std::string`.

Comment: BTW, it is implementation-defined how objects (as `std::string`) are passed to ellipsis (`...` of `printf`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` comes from C library, which predates objects, templates, and function overloading. When you specify `%s` format, the function takes an address of a null-terminated character sequence, and prints it. `printf` has no idea where the string comes from. In fact, it has no idea of its parameter types, because it uses variable-length parameter list feature.

`std::string` is a C++ string. Calling `c_str()` on it produces a pointer to the beginning of a C string, which is suitable for passing to `printf` and other functions expecting a C string.

`cout`, on the other hand, has been built with classes and overloading in mind. There is a special overload for `operator <<` for `std::string`, which lets `cout` and other output streams extract characters from a C++ string.

Answer (score 2):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is originally from `C`, which does not have `std::string`, so the analogous argument type is `const char*` which is what you get when you call `.c_str()`

The reason `std::cout` works with `std::string` is because [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is defined for that class.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) has no idea what a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is.  The protypes for `printf()` are

```
int printf( const char* format, ... );
int fprintf( std::FILE* stream, const char* format, ... );
int sprintf( char* buffer, const char* format, ... );
int snprintf( char* buffer, std::size_t buf_size, const char* format, ... );
```

The reason `std::string` works with `cout` is that `std::string` provieds [`operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) which works with `cout`

Answer (score 0):

string is  a class in c++ stl.
c_str() is a  member function of class string .

The signature is:

> const _CharT* c_str() const { return _M_start; }

now, coming to printf, its signature is:

> int printf ( const char * format, ... );

now, as long as you give it an argument that meets const char * format, it accepts it.